# samrt-contract: call payable function through react frontend

Tags: ethereum, blockchain, solidity, smartcontracts

I tried to call this function through the React app:

```
function getData(address _userAddress, string [] memory _attribute) public payable returns ( string[] memory, Person[] memory){
Some logic . . .

}
```

**It includes emit and its return array,** I always can't see logs from ether scan https://sepolia.etherscan.io/ and from Metamask, the transaction label was Send :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yO84O.png)

but if I call this function by Remix Platform I can see logs :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sShKg.png)

In Metamask, the transaction label was Contract Interaction:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qJQLH.jpg)

This is the way how to interact with my smart contract from the fronted :

```
const result = await  contract.methods.getDataWithSharing(userAddress,selectedAttributes).send({
            from: defaultAccount,
            value:3
        });
```

In my contract, I have many functions that I can interact with through fronted except the above function (payable type).

Dose any one can help me to resolve this issue?

Regards,

Comment: Not sure I follow. What is the exact issue here? If you are looking for `logs`, you wont get that from `contract.methods.getDataWithSharing` response.

Comment: @RobinThomas

Hi Robin, 
Yes I want see logs for getDataWithSharing method, but I can't see it after I call it from frontend app, but if I call it through Remix I can see logs on ether scan.

Comment: Hi @RobinThomas,
I will try it and tell you what happen.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To retrieve the logs of a transaction, you need to retrieve the transaction receipt.

You can do that by:

```
const tx = await contract.methods.getDataWithSharing(attributes).send({
    from: defaultAccount,
    value: 3
});

const txReceipt = await tx.wait();

console.log(txReceipt.logs);
```

The logs are not available when you make a transaction. You have to wait for the transaction to be mined onto a block (which is what `tx.wait` does).

The logs will be available once you get the transaction receipt.